# Join arrays on key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
applesToday= 
[ {product: "apple", period: 1433113200000, qty: -5},
  {product: "apple", period: 1435705200000, qty: -6 },
  {product: "apple", period: 1438383600000, qty: -8}
]

applesYesterday = 
[ {product: "apple", period: 1433113200000, qty: 10},
  {product: "apple", period: 1435705200000, qty: 12 },
  {product: "apple", period: 1438383600000, qty: 16}
]
```

How do I combine them on the period field into:

```
self.applesTodayYesterday= 
[ {product: "apple", period: 1433113200000, qty: -5, qty1: 10},
  {product: "apple", period: 1435705200000, qty: -6, qty1: 12 },
  {product: "apple", period: 1438383600000, qty: -8, qty1: 16}
]
```

I tried googling left join, join on key but could not find anything... is there a nice library that does it?

**Period will always be first day of some month and is a unique key for each array**

EDIT:

Purpose

I am using knockout JS to spit out a table of current inventories and want to preformat the data so that each row is an object in the array. that preformatted data will be used solely by knockout to print into DOM.

Period refers to when apple was picked from the tree

```
[product| period  | quantity | daily change | weekly change ]  [field 1 | field 2 ]
[apple  | apr-15  | 10       | -1           | -12           ]  [8%      | 20%     ]
[apple  | may-15  | 12       | -3           | +14           ]  [1%      | 11%     ]
[TOTAL APPLES     | 22       | -4           | +2            ]  [4%      | 43%     ]
[carrot | apr-15  | 14       | -7           | -12           ]  [8%      | 20%     ]
[carrot | may-15  | 12       | +1           | +14           ]  [1%      | 11%     ]
[TOTAL CARROTS    | 26       | -6           | +2            ]  [4%      | 43%     ]
```

Comment: no, zip won't work. It's going to be tons of different periods all around the array

Comment: Why not combine the quantities? For example, the period "1433113200000" has qty=15. Why keep the quantities separate? If you're going to keep them separate, make a quantity array and put them in there.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this? Are you tracking quantities of apples produced in a certain period?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Fourtheye I have described the problem (how to join on key) and what I tried so far (googling left join )

Comment: Looking at your edit, where do the periods come into play?

Comment: sorry changed now Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/66ybmkj2/)***

Make an object with the keys set to the period of yesterday's apples, and then use that object to set a new qty1 value on today's apples

```
var qtyMap = {};
applesYesterday.forEach(function(a){
 qtyMap[a.period] = a.qty; 
});
applesToday.forEach(function(a){
 a.qty1 = qtyMap[a.period]; 
});
```

Comment: and what if the period is repeated in one of the arrays? (still waiting on that info before i recommended something like this)

Comment: @dandavis - The "period" is the millisecond value of the date. It represents days. It is unlikely days are duplicated in a yesterday/today set of data like this. That is also not shown in the OP's post.